# A weak* dense subset intersected with norm ball contains no ball

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm struggling with this problem in general. 
Represent $\ell^1$ as the space of all real functions $x$ on $S = \{(m,n): m\geq 1, n \geq 1\}$, such that 
$$
\|x\|_1 = \sum |x(m,n)| < \infty
$$

Suppose that $B$ is norm-closed unit ball in $\ell^1$ and $M$ a subspace in $\ell^1$ satisfying the condition. If $x \in \ell^1$ $x \in M$ if
$$
m|x(m,1)| = \sum_{n=2}^\infty x(m,n) \;\;\;\; (m = 1, 2, 3, \ldots)
$$
I need to show that the weak* closure of $M \cap B$ contains no ball.

Rudin provides a suggestion: If $\delta > 0$ and $m > 2/ \delta$, then 
$$
|x(m,1)| \leq \frac{\|x\|}{m} < \frac{\delta}{2}
$$
if $x \in M \cap B$, although $x(m,1) = \delta$ for some $x \in \delta B$. Thus $\delta B$ is not in the weak*-closure of $M \cap B$. Extend this to balls with other centers.

I have already shown that the subset $M$ is weak* dense in $\ell^1$ where $(c_0)^* = \ell^1$ which intuitively makes me think otherwise about the statement of the problem.

I'm really confused with this in general. I know I don't have much of my own thought here like I typically do, but I really just have no idea with this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I made a go at this problem again, but I don't think that I have the concept correct. I am adding my attempt to the proof and putting a bounty on this problem.

Let $B$ be the norm-closed unit ball in $\ell^1$. Suppose $\delta > 0$ and $m > 2/ \delta$, then 
$$
|x(m,1)| \leq \frac{\|x\|}{m} < \frac{\delta}{2}
$$
if $x \in M \cap B$, although $x(m,1) = \delta$ for some $x \in \delta B$. Thus $\delta B$ is not in the weak*-closure of $M \cap B$. To extend this to balls with other centers, we apply a similar argument. Consider $B$ a norm- closed unit ball not centered at $0$ in $\ell^1$. Then we note that $B$ is a shift from the center by some radius $r>0$. In addition for $x \in B$ we now have $\|x\| \leq r+1$, since the ball of radius 1 has been ``shifted" by $r$ from the center. Then suppose that $m > 2(r+1)/(\delta)$, then
$$
|x(m,1)| \leq \frac{\|x\|}{m} < \frac{\delta}{2}
$$
if $x \in M \cap B$. But $x(m,1) = \delta + r$ for some $x \in \delta B + r$. Hence $\delta B$ is not in the weak* closure of $M \cap B$ for balls with other centers.

Comment: $\ell^1$ of what set? You use double indices $x(m,n)$ which seems to indicate that this is not $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The edit should answer your question. The notation for this problem is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof runs the same when you consider the ball centered at $x_0$. Then make all the same assumptions and note that 
$$
|x(m,1) - x_0(m,1)| < \frac{\delta}{2}
$$
but there exists $x(m,1)$ where the absolute value above is equal to $\delta$.